# How do i make the generated link anchor text only?

Tags: javascript, text, anchor

I plan on sharing this to a Facebook group I'm in but I want the link that is generated from putting in the information to be text only and not the url. How can I  do this?

```css
<style>
a:link, a:visited {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover, a:active {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

```html
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
            function generateLink() {
                let link = document.getElementById('link');
                                
                let Group = document.getElementById('GroupID');
                let User  = document.getElementById('UserID');

                                
                let link_string = 'https://m.facebook.com/group/block/?group_id=' 
                                    + Group.value 
                                    + '&user_id='
                                    + User.value;
                link.innerHTML =  '<a href=' + encodeURI(link_string) + '>' + encodeURI(link_string) + '</a>';
                                

                               
                               
            }
 
            </script>
      </head>


<body>
Group ID Number: <input type='text' id='GroupID' onkeyup='generateLink();' /> <br>The Group ID Number is the first set of numbers in the url https://www.facebook.com/groups/<mark>Group ID Number</mark>/user/User ID Number<br><br>
User ID Number: <input type='text' id='UserID' onkeyup='generateLink();' /><br> The User ID Number is the second set of numbers in the url https://www.facebook.com/groups/Group ID Number/user/<mark>User ID Number</mark> <br><br>
<span id='link'></span><br><br>





<a href="https://lookup-id.com/" target="_blank">I don't know what the Group or User ID Number is</a> <br><br>



</body>
```

How do I make the generated link to be a clickable text link only?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question.

Do you want it to look like pure text but clickable?

Use CSS: color: black and text-decoration: none

Comment: After putting in the numbers in the input boxes the part that says "https://m.facebook.com/group/block/?group_id=12345678&user_id=87654321" should simply say "Block User" clicking on it would take you to the url.

Answer (score 0):

```
 link.innerHTML =  '<a href=' + encodeURI(link_string) + '>' + "FaceBook Group" + '</a>';
```

Write like this

Comment: That just makes it look like this. 

https://m.facebook.com/group/block/?group_id=12345678&user_id=87654321>Facebook Group

Comment: You were close. I figured it out though. I got it by removing one of the encodeURI(link_string) and putting quotes after <a href= and before >Block User</a>;

Like this 

link.innerHTML =  '<a href= "'+ encodeURI(link_string) + '" >Block User</a>';

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I removed

> '>' + encodeURI(link_string) +

from the below code (part in bold)

`link.innerHTML =  '<a href=' + encodeURI(link_string) +` **'>' + encodeURI(link_string) +** `'</a>';`

which changes it to

```
link.innerHTML =  '<a href=' + encodeURI(link_string) + '</a>';
```

Then I added quotes after `<a href=` and before `</a>';` to make it look like this.

`link.innerHTML =  '<a href=`**"**`' + encodeURI(link_string) + '`**"**`</a>';`

Then I added a > after the second ending quote.

`link.innerHTML =  '<a href="' + encodeURI(link_string) + '"`**>**`</a>';`

Finally I added the text between >< which looks like this.

`link.innerHTML =  '<a href= "'+ encodeURI(link_string) + '" >`**Block User**`</a>';`

Now it does exactly what I want.